# Using File Browser to Import CSV Data

Tags: python, operator, csv

I'm struggling to import CSV data into my file using the file dialog.

The code I've parsed together opens the file dialog and prints the file name. The problem is that inside of the testOpenFileBrowser operator, I am trying to establish CSVData as a variable that can be used in the main() def. When I try to use the variable in the main definition, it says name 'CSVData' is not defined.

Is there any way to use the CSVData outside of the operator class?

````
import bpy
import csv
import os

from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper
from bpy.props import StringProperty
from bpy.types import Operator

class testOpenFileBrowser(Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_idname = "test.open_filebrowser"
    bl_label = "Open the file browser"
    
    filename_ext = ".csv"
    
    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default= "*csv",
        options={'HIDDEN'},
        maxlen=255,
    )
    
    def execute(self, context):
        
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(self.filepath) 
        
        print('File name:', filename)
        f = open(self.filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        CSVdata = f.read()
        f.close()
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(testOpenFileBrowser)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(testOpenFileBrowser)
    
def main():
    bpy.ops.test.open_filebrowser('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
    print(CSVData)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    
    # test call
```
````

Comment: You can call your `main()` function within the `execute()` method of the operator, see the template provided in the Text Editor for reference: *Text Editor > Templates > Operator File Import* (or just declare a new variable outside of the scope and assign the data in the `execute()` method). Does this help?

Comment: Maybe my code to import .csv files into blender will help:
https://github.com/simonbroggi/blender_spreadsheet_import/

What I do is create a new mesh and save all the csv data into mesh attributes.
The nice thing about this is that you can view the csv data in the spreadsheet view in blender.

Comment: Hello, I suggest you familiarize yourself with function scope and the global keyword in python. That's not really related to the blender API